# Linkedin authentication cancel workflow opens new tab instead of redirect in same page

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn in my angular 2.x app. Where i used pop ups to authenticate user. For successful sign in its working perfectly by posting the data back to parent. But for cancel or failure linkedin is opening a new tab and closing the original pop up which is not expected.

Can anyone guide to fix this.

Code sample:

```
const url = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/linkedin/callback&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile`;
    this.windowHandle = window.open(url, 'linkedin login', 'height=600,width=550');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be from LinkedIn itself. If the user cancels the authorization, LinkedIn seems to close the window.
Refer [this](https://community.auth0.com/t/when-user-cancels-linkedin-login-in-popup-mode-a-new-window-tab-is-opened/6765) for more details.